# What is happening during assignment to a dataframe by lapply

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

Given a dataframe df and a function f which is applied to df:

df[] <- lapply(df, f)

What is the magic R is performing to replace columns in df with collection of vectors in the list from lapply?  I see that the result from lapply is a list of vectors having the same names as the dataframe df.  I assume some magic mapping is being done to map the vectors to df[], which is the collection of columns in df (methinks).  Just works?  Trying to better understand so that I remember what to use the next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A data.frame is merely a list of vectors having the same length. You can see it using `is.list(a_data_frame)`. It will return `TRUE`.

`[]` can have different meaning or action depending of the object it is applied on. It even can be redefined as it is in fact a function.

`[]` allows to subset or insert vector columns from data.frame.

`df[1]` get the first column
`df[1] <- 2` replace the first column with `2` (repeated in order to have the same length as other columns)

`df[]` return the whole data.frame
`df[] <- list(c1,c2,c3)` sets the content of the data.frame replacing it's current content

Plus a wide number of other way to access or set data in a data.frame (by column name, by subset of rows, of columns, ...)

Comment: "df[] is the whole data frame"  I think this is the key for me.  The list returned from lapply is the same shape as the data frame the function is applied to.  Since (in this case) the receiver of the result is the entire data frame and the function is also applied to the entire data frame, then things work out nice.  If the target were a subset, df[1:5] for example, then the same subset should appear in the lapply statement, and vice versa, or the results could be mucked up.  Reasonable?